# Is there a way to have an ::after element like an icon after a link ignore punctuation and appear after it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using external link icons on my site and calling them using a class `"external"`. It works fine, but in a case like this:

"Here is some text and the last word will be a [link](http://#)."

my external link icon appears after the word "link" and the "." trails after the icon. One solution would be to just include the period in the link, but I don't want my link styles affecting my period. Is there anything I can do to have `a.external::after` ignore periods and commas and appear after them?

Here is sort of what the HTML and CSS I'm working with looks like.

```
<p>
Here is some text and the last word will be a <a href="#" class="external">link</a>.
</p>
```

```
a.external::after{
    content:'';
    position: relative;
    left: 0.1em;
    height: 9px;
    width: 9px;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    background: url('http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_423119.png');
    background-size: auto;
    background-size: 9px 9px;
    vertical-align: 5px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the pseudo element to the `p` tag itself. You can make the selection more specific by giving the `p` tag a class.

```css
p.p-link::after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  left: 0.1em;
  height: 9px;
  width: 9px;
  margin-right: 0.1em;
  background: url('http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_423119.png');
  background-size: auto;
  background-size: 9px 9px;
  vertical-align: 5px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p class="p-link">
  Here is some text and the last word will be a <a href="#" class="external">link</a>.
</p>
<p>Some other paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that all the other <p> elements in my site would have the external icon attached to them though? D:

Comment: You can make the selection more specific by giving it a class. Check my updated answer @lehtia

Comment: I think that is one solution, but I'm looking for a way to apply it specifically to the link because these external links may appear in the middle of a sentence, or at the end, or right before a comma, etc.

Comment: @lehtia What behavior do you except in each of these situations i.e. middle of the sentence, end, before comma?